# Android NDK get call stack information in function

Tags: android-ndk

I am writing a function in native code and want to know from inside the function what other functions called it so I decide to use `java.lang.Thread.dumpStack` in my c code, but seens not working. Anybody know other possible ways, please? Thanks much!

below is the code:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved)
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "TIM", "JNI_OnLoad Called");

    JNIEnv *env = NULL;

    if (vm->GetEnv((void **)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK)
    {
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "TIM", "GetEnv Failed");
            return JNI_ERR;
    }

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "TIM", "GetEnv Called");

    // public static void dumpStack ()

    jclass cls2 = env->FindClass("java/lang/Thread");
    if(!cls2)
    {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "TIM", "FindClass  Failed");
        return JNI_ERR;
    }

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "TIM", "FinClass Called");


    jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls2, "dumpStack", "()V");
    if(!mid)
    {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "TIM", "GetStaticMethodID loadLibrary Failed");
        return JNI_ERR;
    }

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "TIM", "GetStaticMethodID Called");

    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls2, mid);

    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```

and this is the error i got:

```
04-24 11:44:48.217: D/dalvikvm(4140): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.tim.myjni/lib/libmyjni.so 0x413486d8
04-24 11:44:48.267: D/dalvikvm(4140): Added shared lib /data/data/com.tim.myjni/lib/libmyjni.so 0x413486d8
04-24 11:44:48.267: I/TIM(4140): JNI_OnLoad Called
04-24 11:44:48.277: I/TIM(4140): GetEnv Called
04-24 11:44:48.277: I/TIM(4140): FinClass Called
04-24 11:44:48.277: I/TIM(4140): GetStaticMethodID Called
04-24 11:44:48.287: W/System.err(4140): java.lang.Throwable: stack dump
04-24 11:44:48.348: W/System.err(4140):     at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:496)
04-24 11:44:48.348: W/System.err(4140):     at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
04-24 11:44:48.377: W/System.err(4140):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:368)
04-24 11:44:48.377: W/System.err(4140):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
04-24 11:44:48.407: W/System.err(4140):     at com.tim.myjni.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:53)
04-24 11:44:48.407: W/System.err(4140):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-24 11:44:48.417: W/System.err(4140):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
04-24 11:44:48.417: W/System.err(4140):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
04-24 11:44:48.417: W/System.err(4140):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1870)
04-24 11:44:48.417: W/System.err(4140):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
04-24 11:44:48.417: W/System.err(4140):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
04-24 11:44:48.417: W/System.err(4140):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
04-24 11:44:48.447: W/System.err(4140):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-24 11:44:48.447: W/System.err(4140):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-24 11:44:48.467: W/System.err(4140):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
04-24 11:44:48.467: W/System.err(4140):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 11:44:48.477: W/System.err(4140):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-24 11:44:48.477: W/System.err(4140):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-24 11:44:48.477: W/System.err(4140):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-24 11:44:48.477: W/System.err(4140):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not an error, that's the stack trace.  It just happens to be printed like an exception.

The code in Thread is:

```
public static void dumpStack() {
    new Throwable("stack dump").printStackTrace();
}
```

And that's what you have in the log -- note the first line:

`W/System.err(4140): java.lang.Throwable: stack dump`

Comment: thanks for the explanation fadden. looks  I am printing a Java call stack, is there any ways to print the native code say, C call stack?

Comment: I don't think there's a public function for doing that from the NDK.  Internally there's the `CallStack` class in libutils, which you would use by creating a `CallStack` object, calling `update()`, and then `dump()` to print it to the log.  On recent versions of Android (>= Jellybean) you could also use `kill(getpid(), SIGQUIT)` to cause Dalvik to dump its threads; since your thread would be in `NATIVE` state you'd get a native stack dump along with the Dalvik trace.  You'd likely need to pull that out of /data/anr/traces.txt -- watch logcat for info.

Comment: Thanks again fadden, I really appreciate for the help. I don't want to crash my APP so better try to use the CallStack class.

Comment: To be clear, "killing" your process with `SIGQUIT` just sends a signal that is caught by a signal handler in Dalvik, which pauses the VM, dumps all thread stacks, and then resumes.  Your app won't actually die.  The `kill()` system call is arguably misnamed.